# Need an algorithm for an outward spiral starting from the origin on a grid in $n$-dimensions.

Tags: probability, sampling

Need an algorithm for an outward spiral starting from the origin on a grid in $n$-dimensions. I have the answer in 2-d, and looking to extend.  Interest here is for "inverse CDF" sampling from an $n$-dimensional probability distribution.

Comment: You need to describe what the path is much more clearly.  An outward spiral is enough in 2D, but not in more than that.

Comment: Good point, Ross.  Was going to say that distance from each grid point to origin as you spiral outward has to either increase or stay the same, but that is not true for my 2D spiral.  Maybe I need to specify that the spiral would fill all space, and that for each subsequent grid point on the spiral the ith coordinate can change by only +/- 1 grid interval.